# Efficient media transfers in Node and Electron

Tags: node.js, electron

As a toy project for Electron, I'm trying to rewrite a WPF media management application and would like to get up to speed on what would be the best means of loading media (namely images, but later video) through node's `fs` and get it into a webpage for Electron to render.

Currently I've got a basic working setup using Base64 encoding:

```
function getImage(imageID, success) {
    fs.readFile('f:/pictures/2.jpg', function(err, data) {
        if (err) throw err;                    
        success(Buffer.from(data).toString('base64'));
    });
}
```

and rendering it like so in my html:

```
api.getImage(0, (result) => {
    $('#mainContent').append('<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,' + result + '" />');
});
```

This doesn't strike me as the most efficient method to do so.  Base64 conversions are helpful for cross technology boundaries, but not the most efficient way to do things.

Some other considerations I had:

- Host the file directory via node so I can link to the file directly from my webpage (this is not ideal as files can come from anywhere on the local filesystem)
- Use node to copy the file from the filesystem to the served directory so I can link to it via html (this would be slow: disk IO and whatnot)
- Pass the raw file buffer back to the webpage somehow (this seems like it should be the way to go, but not sure how to render it in "traditional" html)

Considering that I may want to process 50 or 100 images or so at a time (including possible resizing for thumbnail views: something I was able to do in WPF effectively by optimizing the decoding for the `BitmapImage`), what would be the general approach to follow?

To clarify, I'm not asking so much about async/process blocking as I am the data transfer itself.

Comment: will the files be coming from a `dialog.showOpenDialog` or you have to just hardcode the filenames